# How do the start options effect your world?

Tags: pixel-piracy

When starting a new game in Pixel Piracy, you have a few options how you want your world to be like.

What exactly do these options change? Or is this feature not implemented yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes these questions do impact the game.

First Set of Questions

What do you think about ___?

**It's Sickening**, filled with pirates, monsters, and hardships. (Monsters) - Increases the amount of monster and pirates on the world map.

**Fascinating**, an intriguing assortment of inhabitants roam the land. (Mystery) - Increases islands and the type of monsters that will spawn on each island. (Careful! It may spawn some strong ones)

**Unpleasant**, a province filled with dire corners and unrelenting troubles. (Drama) - increases ports, thieves on each ports, and problematic crew members.

Second Set of Questions

What is the most recent event that ever happened in the land?

**A great war tore the populace apart.** (More ship encounters) -Will get attacked by pirates more frequently during your travels.

**A plague that killed many innocents.** (Plague) - Crew members are more prone to scurvy, etc. (Get a Doctor ASAP if chosen)

**A very rare comet flyby brought along bad omens.** (Long Dangerous Nights) -Travel time to each place/ encounter will take longer than normal. Make sure to pack a lot of food and hire a sailor. Long nights causes lots of problems caused by drunkards, thieves, and greedy crew members.

Third Set of Questions

How do you remember your father?

**He was a brave captain, his nickname was Curraaage.** (Falcon Blade) - Your captain starts off with 600 g and a 4 damage sword. It does give a lot of benefits for easy clean up of level 1 ships.

**He was a lazy alcoholic known as Horke the flatulent.** (Extra starting Pirate) - You start off with 600 g and a(n) extra crew mate named 'Horke".

**He was a cowardly sailor that went by the name Peonpants.** (+15 TP) - You start with 600 g and gain an extra 15 TP.

More information can be found in the source but i think this answered your question.

Source : http://pixelpiracy.gamepedia.com/Strategy_Guide